# Bean not injected with CDI and Arquillian test failed when SolrServer is used

Tags: java, solr, cdi, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm

My Arquillian test looks like this:

```
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;      
    import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
    import javax.inject.Inject;     
    import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.DefaultDeployment;

    @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    @DefaultDeployment(type = Type.WAR)
    public class CDIArquillianTest {

        @Inject
        private SomeClass someclass;

        @Test
        public void testInjection() {
            assertNotNull(someclass);
            assertTrue(someclass.printI().contains("my string"));
        }

        @Test
        public void testCDIContainerPresence() throws Exception {
            assertNotNull(CDI.current());
        }
    }
```

Injected class:

```
    import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;

    @ApplicationScoped
    public class SomeClass{ 
        private SolrServer solrServer;

        public SomeClass(){     
        }

        public String printI(){
            String somestr = "my string";
            return somestr;
        }       
    }
```

Inside of it, there is SolrServer class, which makes the problem. Without the class inclussion, everything works fine. Error message tells that my SomeClass was ignored, because SolrServer class wasn't found. 
How can I deal with this error? Should I include this SolrServer class manually? Can't use @DefaultDeployment here? Maybe SolrServer is somehow incompatible with CDI?

Error message:

```
2017-01-11 15:59:17,956 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CDIArquillianTest.jar".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CDIArquillianTest.jar".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeClass with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private xx.CDIArquillianTest.someclass
  at xx.CDIArquillianTest.someclass(CDIArquillianTest.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class xx.SomeClass is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader].
```

Some more stacktrace:

```
2017-01-11 15:59:16,825 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from xxSomeClass because of underlying class loading error: Type org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 15:59:16,825 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class xx.SomeClass
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.createContext(FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.SecurityActions.getDeclaredFields(SecurityActions.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:179)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:156)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedFields.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:80)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:175)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 38 more
```

Pom.xml file:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <version.wildfly.swarm>2017.1.1</version.wildfly.swarm>
    <version.wildfly.arquillian>1.1.10.Final</version.wildfly.arquillian>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <solr.version>4.10.3-cdh5.9.0</solr.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.arquillian}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Wildfly Swarm Fractions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-cdh5.7.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Solar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-cell</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Other Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After answer from Ken I added @DefaultDeployment(type = Type.WAR) to arquilian test, and now deployment of this test works fine, but test failed with bellow message (without SolrServer works all the time fine):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members
            at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:135)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.enrich(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:78)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
        ...
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException : WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeClass with qualifiers @Default
          at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private xx.CDIArquillianTest.someclass
          at xx.CDIArquillianTest.someclass(CDIArquillianTest.java:0)
         [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException]
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:81)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:69)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1110)
            at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.createInjectionTarget(ForwardingBeanManager.java:201)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectNonContextualInstance(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:143)
            at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:125)
            ... 115 more
        Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException : WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeClass with qualifiers @Default
          at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private xx.CDIArquillianTest.someclass
          at xx.CDIArquillianTest.someclass(CDIArquillianTest.java:0)
         [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException]
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateProducer(Validator.java:417)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.validateProducer(InjectionTargetService.java:36)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.validate(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:135)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:79)
            ... 120 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be that the deployment being created is a JAR and not a WAR, which is why the solr libraries aren't present.

You will need to use:

```
@DefaultDeployment(type = WAR)
```

instead of just

```
@DefaultDeployment
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I made as you suggested: @DefaultDeployment(type = Type.WAR), and now deployment of Aquirian test works correct, but still, JUnit test is failed. I added trace message to the post above

Comment: Github project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/mielniczekm/cdi-simpleTest/tree/master